# Discussing the technical errors with referencing to unofficial experience

Tags: research-process, citations, thesis, presentation, negative-results

I would like to present and discuss the technical issues of used software, which crippled/damaged some of my final data during the data processing (Still I have a sufficient amount of data for the conclusion). However, I am not quite sure if I can discuss the technical issues in my thesis with user posts from software user forums. Of course, the same experience can support my evidence.
Is it possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be OK. Just explain it in the most academic style possible, clearly and concisely.

Maybe you can explain the problems in your own words, and explain how you have verified the information by your own experience. Then at the end state that some of these points were gathered from software forums (which you can cite) and you have verified that they are accurate yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems reasonabe!